# How to gradle publish a non SNAPSHOT?

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I am using the maven-publish plugin to publish to an internal repo.  What I can't figure out is how to publish so that the -SNAPSHOT is not part of the tag.  I know if I am in master branch in git it does but I need it to do it on another non-master branch (release/*).  How do I tell it that this is not a SNAPSHOT branch?

Google is not being helpful the past few days.

Comment: At least with current versions of Gradle/maven-publish plugin, we add `-SNAPSHOT` in our `build.gradle`...  just set the `version`.  Verify you're not setting it somewhere.